# Can't set variable in destination view within prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm adding a tableView to my app which shows some news items, upon click a new view gets loaded with a webview which shows the complete article. Everything besides setting a variable (newsURL) in the destination view works. I've been trying for a while but I'm not getting it to work.

**The prepareForSegue func:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowNewsItem" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NewsViewControllerItem {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                destination.newsURL = self.News![indexPath]["link"].stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have debugged it, and everything is working except for the third line, it simply doesn't continue after that, so I'm guessing the destination is false/nil. I have also tried doing `let destination = NewsViewControllerItem()` but that doesn't help either.

I have defined `var newsURL = String()` in the NewsViewControllerItem and I am trying to output it in the viewDidLoad, but it doesn't output anything.

Hopefully someone has an idea how to solve this, if additional information/code is needed please let me know.

Comment: Why the 'if' keyword in every statement? Also double check your syntax.

Comment: Just to check where it's going wrong, what's wrong with my syntax? Do you know the issue?

Comment: Sorry I was comparing your if statements to objective c where parenthesis  () are required. Something else could be going wrong here.

Comment: Can you debug and see if your newsURL property gets assigned a value in your detail view controller. Does your detail view controller show up? also do you have a segue setup in your storyboard? How is it setup?

Comment: I have a segue setup and named it "ShowNewsItem". It is calling the above function like it should, but it's going wrong at the let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NewsViewControllerItem part.

Comment: and yeah, it actually loads up the view controller as it should

Comment: can you try removing your if condition at if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NewsViewControllerItem and try?

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work either. I have also tried destination = NewsViewControllerItem()

Comment: Does it even go to this line? destination.newsURL = self.News![indexPath]["link"].stringValue. Did you try a breakpoint and see if the value is getting passed? Can you try without any if conditions at all? Just keep the segue identifier if condition

Comment: It stops at the if destination line, if I remove the if statement I get an error that destination is nil.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line and see what is segue.destinationViewController and not destination

Comment: segue.destinationViewController is a UIViewController, the NewsViewControllerItem I guess, so that works.

Comment: That may not be correct. Check your storyboard for the news view controller item. Have you given it a custom class of NewsViewControllerItem in the properties panel on the right?? It may be failing to type cast because of that.

Comment: Yes, I have set the Class to NewsViewControllerItem, isn't this correct?

Comment: That seems correct. And you are sure you are segueing to that class right? You've put breakpoints there and checked?

Comment: Yes, the if segue.identifier == "ShowNewsItem" { confirms this I guess, as this returns true. Maybe you want to view the project on teamviewer? I'm really stuck on this for a long time now haha.

Comment: sure let me see if I can help. pass on the details

Comment: http://0bin.net/paste/2KpnFXf9UcVjDQ-e#m9UOpCP8Buzzeu6IS0Sgn82SjIdK4pprIcGmrxEh6Kr

Comment: Please see answer below, and if it solved your problem please accept it (click the tick mark below the voting buttons). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as we discussed, the problem was in the fact that the `NewsViewControllerItem` was embedded in a Navigation controller, which was not needed as your parent view controller was already embedded in a Navigation Controller.

Once you remove the embedding of the `NewsViewControllerItem` it should work just fine.

Hope this helps.